# Swapping of common values in 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframe as shown below

df1

```
PMID       References
12755609    2755610
2844048     987
```

df2

```
 PMID       Authors
 2844048    CohKBJKenUP
 2844048    Markar AB
 12755609    GuarnerUJ
 12755609    RoshanRJ
 2755610     John HV
 2755610     Tony KR
 987         Maroi KK
```

I wanted to compare the column from df1 (PMID & References) to the PMID of df2, if there is matching values, the values in a column of df (PMID & References) will be replaced by the authors. Each PMID or references from df1 can have multiple authors in df2 like  2844048 has 2 two authors(CohKBJKenUP, Markar AB), so results should contain all possible combination

The possible output is like

```
PMID       References
GuarnerUJ   John HV
RoshanRJ    John HV
GuarnerUJ   Tony KR
RoshanRJ    Tony KR
CohKBJKenUP Maroi KK
Markar AB   Maroi KK
```

I have tried using for loop but it's giving a memory issue due to large file size.

I have tried this also but this os giving an error

```
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

df1['PMID'] = df1['PMID'].map(df2.set_index('PMID')['author'])
```

Please suggest the possibility to get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='PMID')
df.drop(['PMID'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df = df.merge(df2,left_on='References',right_on='PMID')
df.drop(['References','PMID'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.columns = ['PMID','References']
print(df)


    PMID        References
0   GuarnerUJ   John HV
1   GuarnerUJ   Tony KR
2   RoshanRJ    John HV
3   RoshanRJ    Tony KR
4   CohKBJKenUP Maroi KK
5   Markar AB   Maroi KK
```